# Solr basic authentication permission settings

Tags: solr, basic-authentication, solrj, solrcloud, user-roles

My goal is to have only user A can read collection 1 and only user B can read collection 2. I thought by adding collection attribute before pre-defined "read" might help but it didn't. I have tested many ways but didn't work. I saw the example in [here](https://lucidworks.com/2015/08/17/securing-solr-basic-auth-permission-rules/) but it didn't work.
Right now I have:

```
Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks:
<i>This is not italic</i>, and [this is not a link](https://example.com)
{"authentication":{
"blockUnknown":true,
"class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
"credentials":{...},
"":{"v":0}},
  "authorization":{
    "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "permissions":[
      {
        "name":"security-edit",
        "role":"admin",
        "index":1},
      {
        "name":"permission1",
        "collection":"collection1",
        "path":"/select",
        "role":"readColletion1",
        "index":2}],
"user-role":{
  "solr":"admin",
  "userA":"readColletion1",
  "userB":"readColletion2",},
"":{"v":0}}}
```

When user B can still access collection1 for no reason.

Have anyone did this before? Hope I can get some tips, Thanks!
I have been stuck for a whole day... Desperately need help

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with the same problem for a few days now and I've figured out a solution.

I have 2 users luigi and mario who are my customers who are allowed to use my instance of solr and who each have their own collections. They should not be able to see or work in any way on any collection that does not belong to them.

They each have full access to their own collections, however.

Here's my solution for solr 8.1.1

```
"authorization": {
"class": "solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
"permissions": [
  {
    "collection": null,
    "params": {
      "action": [
        "LIST",
        "CREATE"
      ]
    },
    "role": "admin",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "collection": "mario",
    "path": [
      "/*"
    ],
    "method": [
      "GET",
      "PUT",
      "POST",
      "DELETE",
      "HEAD"
    ],
    "role": "mario",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "collection": "luigi",
    "path": [
      "/*"
    ],
    "method": [
      "GET",
      "PUT",
      "POST",
      "DELETE",
      "HEAD"
    ],
    "role": "luigi",
    "index": 3
  }
],
"user-role": {
  "solr": "admin",
  "mario": "mario",
  "luigi": "luigi"
},
"": {
  "v": 17
}
}
```

You have to define permissions for each role in your system, otherwise a role with undefined permissions is allowed to to do anything. You also have to define a permission for each action you would like to secure, otherwise any role is allowed to perform the action.

Example: The index 1 permission is required to forbid mario and luigi from listing or creating collections. It would, however be even better to use the predefined permissions of collection_admin_edit and collection_admin_read. Because by defining only the actions LIST and CREATE at index 1, luigi and mario are still allowed to do all other actions. In this example, I was still able to DELETE the collection mario as user luigi using the above mentioned set of permissions.

In this context I should note, that the [solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html) mentions to put the most restrictive permission to index 1. Because the permissions are consulted for each request in order from top to bottom.

I hope this helps anyone struggling with the same problem.